# Why can AWS Lambda not read a test event sent to it via the API Gateway test?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I am writing an application on AWS Lambda in Python that expects to receive information that gets placed in the event dictionary.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    try:
        task = event["task"]
    except:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps('Cound not find the requested task.')
        }
```

When I test the JSON event below within the Lambda console, it is understood by the function, which then does its thing.

```
{
  "task": "returnID",
  "username": "noneofyourbusiness",
  "password": "pleasedonotask"
}
```

But when I place this event in the test provided within the AWS API Gateway (console version), it fails to find event["task"].

What else should I check?  Is there some other resource that I should consult?

I tried putting the JSON in the query string (even though the method should be POST) and tried again using both POST and GET.

Comment: add `print(event)` and check what actually `event` is.

Comment: Without going through the test, event is 

{'task': 'returnRecord', 'providerID': 9999, 'table': 'Food_Pantries_en', 'username': 'xxxxxxx', 'password': 'yyyyyyy'}

Comment: you usually send stuff like this through as POST or GET parameters ... that are attached to the `event["requestContext"]`  and/or `event['queryStringParameters']`(or something like that...)

Comment: Without going through the test, event is 

{'task': 'returnRecord', 'providerID': 9999, 'table': 'Food_Pantries_en', 'username': 'xxxxxxx', 'password': 'yyyyyyy'}

Through the API Gateway test, it is:  

{'resource': '/feedut_update_services', 'path': '/feedut_update_services', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'headers': None, 'multiValueHeaders': None, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'AIDAS7HH5S3CPW4AGY5MZ'}, 'domainName': 'testPrefix.testDomainName', 'apiId': 'l0ap06t0ui'}, 'body': '{"task":"returnID","username":"xxxxxxx,"password":"yyyyyyy"}', 'isBase64Encoded': False} 

(14 lines wiped)

Comment: So the test -- and maybe the API -- add over 1000 characters of text and the JSON event is tucked into another JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your `task` is inside `body` of the event. You should use:

```
task = event["body"]["task"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it did not work.  Also, there are times that I was able to do task = event["foo"] from within a Python Lambda on AWS.

Comment: Maybe there is a way I can convince Lambda to ignore the header or the REST API not to send it?

Comment: @WarrenEckels This means that your question does not reflect your code nor event.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have realized, events come with far more information than just the payload itself. You can checkout the docs for the event format and how you should respond.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event